# check if child_process has ended in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I am creating a cakefile using node.js and want to know if a child_process has ended before moving on the next one.

```
{exec} = require 'child_process'
 exec 'casperjs test.js', (err, stdout, stderr) ->
        err && throw err
        log stdout
        if //exec has finished
          log "finished executing"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the callback of [`exec`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) is called, the process has already been terminated. There's no need to add an additional check.

For [`spawn`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), you can bind an [`exit` event listener](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit).

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly you can use 'execSync", in order to go on step by step

```
var c = require('child_process');
var cliCommand = 'ls';
var result = c.execSync(cliCommand);
```